# Error using imapsync to migrate from Courier-IMAP to MS Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, imapsync, courier-imap

I got error when using imapsync:

```
+ NO msg #8902 [6LRM0SNoLvi5ehuhf0ysRA:2796] in INBOX
+ Copying msg #8902:2796 to folder INBOX
flags from : [][]
Couldn't append msg #8902 (Subject:[Kaka]) to folder INBOX: 91 BAD Command Argument Error. 11

++++ Statistics ++++
Time                   : 24 sec
Messages transfered    : 0
Messages skipped       : 0
Total bytes transfered : 0
Total bytes skipped    : 0
Total bytes error      : 4661237
Detected 91 errors
```

What is the meaning of this error msg? How can I resolve it?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I've downloaded wrong version.

Get the latest and it'll be fine.
The download site: http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/dist/
Notice that ver number 1.99 is older than ver 1.315.